# How select unique minimum value from more tables

Tags: mysql, subquery, in-subquery

I have following problem.

In MySQL I have two tables:

```
Table A
---------------------------
| idOffer| price
| 4      | 20
| 4      | 30
| 5      | 15
| 5      | 18
| 6      | 6
| 4      | 9
--------------------------------------------------

Table B
---------------------------
| idOffer| price
| 4      | 60
| 4      | 70
| 5      | 10
| 5      | 8
| 6      | 90
| 6      | 100
--------------------------------------------------
```

Is there possible query, which return result like

```
| idOffer| price
| 4      | 20
| 5      | 8
| 6      | 6
```

Comment: I assume the the price of 9 should be the return value for 4 unless that was a typo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option with a `union all` statement:

```
select idoffer, min(price)
from (
    select idoffer, price from tablea
    union all
    select idoffer, price from tableb
) t
group by idoffer
```