# How to get the smallest unique integer from a table in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, unique

I have a table that has two columns, name and number. I'd like to get the **smallest *unique*** number from the provided table. for example

| name | number |
| --- | --- |
| john | 1 |
| abbey | 3 |
| afton | 2 |
| mike | 1 |
| lucas | 5 |
| jack | 2 |
| jake | 4 |
| tony | 3 |

For example, the smallest value here is 1 but the smallest **unique** value is 4
How could I make a query in SQLite that can do that?
I did see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38816544/how-select-unique-minimum-value-from-more-tables) but it's not what I want

Edit: This is the code I tried

```sql
Select a.name, a.number
From Result a
Having count(a.smallest) = 1
Group By a.smallest;
```

It returned "Error: near line XX: near "Group": syntax error"
I also tried

```sql
Select a.name, a.number
From Result a
Where count(a.smallest) = 1
Group By a.smallest;
```

But it returned "Error: near line XX: misuse of aggregate: count()"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try aggregating your table by the number, restricting to numbers only appearing once, and then retaining the smallest number:

```sql
SELECT number
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY number
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY number
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: OH so you have to put "Group By" before the count! I did try this method but I didnt realize that the line order matters. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can group by number and set the condition in the HAVING clause that the number is unique.
Then pick the smallest number with `MIN()` window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MIN(number) OVER () AS min_number
FROM tablename
GROUP BY number
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=38c462f575552f431e394c2b9bd9476d).

Comment: Thanks! This does work quite well and short!

Answer (score 1):

Using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT a.*, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY number) AS cnt
      FROM Result a) sub
WHERE cnt = 1
ORDER BY number
LIMIT 1;
```

Output:

```
name    number  cnt
jake    4   1
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=59d1422a5a18b38ade2de43e404baac9)**

Comment: This looks good! I just started with SQL so this is kind of intimidating but I'll get used to it soon

Comment: @Enderhoang Actually it is very simple. Windowed COUNT(*) counts the number of occurence per number, then outer query filter only the ones that are "single" and ORDER BY number LIMIT 1 - return the lowerst one. It also provides entire row(which seems to be the case as your trial are: "`Select a.name, a.number"` and not only number.